# Замена стандартного заполнителя input

Tags: html, jquery, css, input

Возможна ли замена стандартного заполнителя input[type=password]. Желательно, что бы вместо точек обычных, вставлялась скажем моя картинка.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На  *input[type=password]* невозмоно, т.к. это системный компонент браузеров. 
Но восоздать такое вполне возможно с помощью Javascript, но я не рекомендую т.к. будут проблемы с безопасностю. 
Но с помощью **CSS3** возможно изменить вид стандартного заполнителя.

```
input { -webkit-text-security: none; }
input { -webkit-text-security: circle; }
input { -webkit-text-security: square; }
input { -webkit-text-security: disc; /* По умолчанию */ }
```

У меня оно работает пока что на Хроме, на других не проверил. 
А вот рабочий [код](http://jsfiddle.net/estelle/8WpNg/)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, придется делать на js.

Comment: Если честно я такое не рекомендую. Но если нет другого варианта то это единственный выход.